# Why do combo boxes not work if using a custom popup?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jpopupmenu

I'm trying to replace the UI for popup menus with one where the corners of the menu are properly rounded. Appearance-wise everything looks right, but I noticed when using combo boxes, the option doesn't actually get selected when you select the menu item. It's as if the window disappears before it can process the mouse pressed event.

Interestingly, it does register the event if you hold the mouse down and release it over the desired option. Keyboard navigation also works correctly.

In a debugger, I was able to see a `postEvent()` being called with the `MOUSE_PRESSED` event, but couldn't figure out where it went after that. `MOUSE_RELEASED` is what should actually trigger selecting the item, but I can't see one of those being fired at all.

I condensed my code down to a much simpler version (without all the rendering stuff) which still causes the issue.

If you remove the call to `UIManager.put` which sets in my custom UI, everything works correctly.

PopupMenuTest.java:

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class PopupMenuTest implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PopupMenuTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        UIManager.put("PopupMenuUI", CustomPopupMenuUI.class.getName());

        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {
            "Apples", "Bananas", "Cantaloupes" });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

CustomPopupMenuUI.java:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.Popup;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPopupMenuUI;

public class CustomPopupMenuUI extends BasicPopupMenuUI {
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration") // called via reflection
    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent component) {
        return new CustomPopupMenuUI();
    }

    @Override
    public Popup getPopup(JPopupMenu popupMenu, int x, int y) {
        return new CustomPopup(popupMenu, x, y);
    }

    private static class CustomPopup extends Popup {
        private final JWindow popupWindow;

        CustomPopup(JPopupMenu popupMenu, int ownerX, int ownerY) {
            this.popupWindow = new JWindow();
            popupWindow.setContentPane(popupMenu);
            popupWindow.setLocation(ownerX, ownerY);
        }

        @Override
        public void show() {
            this.popupWindow.pack();
            this.popupWindow.setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void hide() {
            this.popupWindow.setVisible(false);
            this.popupWindow.removeAll();
            this.popupWindow.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found a workaround of using the normal popup factory's existing window and then setting my stuff onto that window to paint the border and drop shadow. :)  But I'm still pretty curious why naively creating a window of my own results in one that doesn't work.